# MPAndroidChart multiple line data

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to plot baby weight vs CDC weight charts. I have percentile vs week mapping for CDC data (about 24 weeks). The baby data has just 2-3 points (and the number of points are variable).

How can I plot this using MP Android Chart. I get this error...

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: One or more of the DataSet Entry arrays are longer than the x-values array of this ChartData object.
```

Comment: Have you checked that all your DataSet arrays are no longer than 24 weeks? (I am assuming that the weeks is what you mapped to the X-Axis)

Answer (score 2):

your x-values and y-values arrays must be in equal length, or the y-values need to be smaller. Otherwise its cause Exception.